# React Google Maps Stuck on "Loading" when putting the StandaloneSearchBox in the code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-google-maps

I have a page on my react js where I am trying allow companies to register for my website and add their locations so that other companies come over for rentals, purchases, etc. I also need Markers if I can add them. I have gotten my Google Maps on my page, however, I can't get the Search bar (`StandaloneSearchBox`) on the page because it is stuck on "Loading". Here is my code:

```
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, StandaloneSearchBox, LoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';




const initialState = {
  company: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  isMember: true,
}

  const Register = () => {

    const mapContainerStyle = {
      height: "400px",
      width: "800px"
    }
    
    const center = {
      lat: -3.745,
      lng: -38.523
    };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

  // global state and useNavigate
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
  }

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target)
  }
  const handleLoad = ref => this.searchBox = ref;
  const handlePlacesChanged = () => console.log(this.searchBox.getPlaces());
    return (
        <body class="page-template-default page page-id-13">
        <header class="site-header">
              <div class="container">
              <h1 class="school-logo-text float-left"><a href="/landing"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a></h1>
                         <div class="site-header__util">
                                        </div>
                </div>
                </header>

    <div class="page-banner">
     <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style={ { backgroundImage: "url('connection.jpg')" } }></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title">Register</h1>
        <div class="page-banner__intro">
            <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container container--narrow page-section">
  <h2 class="headline headline--tiny">Want to join and connect with companies? Sign up and get your company out there:</h2>
  
    <label class="header">Profile Photo:</label>
      <input id="image" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture></input>
    <label class="company-name">Company Name</label>
      <div class="company-input">
        <input text="headline headline--input" placeholder="Enter Company"></input>
      </div>
    <label class="company-email">Email</label>
          <div class="email-input">
          <input text="headline headline--input" placeholder="Enter Email"></input>
          </div>

     <label class="company-map">Map</label>   
<div class="map-input">
    
  <LoadScript
    googleMapsApiKey='API_HERE'>
        <GoogleMap
          id="map"
          mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={10}
        >
          
          <StandaloneSearchBox
          onLoad={handleLoad}
          onPlacesChanged={handlePlacesChanged}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Customized your placeholder"
            style={{
              boxSizing: `border-box`,
              border: `1px solid transparent`,
              width: `240px`,
              height: `32px`,
              padding: `0 12px`,
              borderRadius: `3px`,
              boxShadow: `0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`,
              fontSize: `14px`,
              outline: `none`,
              textOverflow: `ellipses`,
              position: "absolute",
              left: "50%",
              marginLeft: "-120px"
            }}
          />
        </StandaloneSearchBox>
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>

            </div>  
    </div>
    

    <footer class="site-footer">
                  <div class="site-footer__inner container container--narrow">
                    <div class="group">
                      <div class="site-footer__col-one">
                        <h1 class="school-logo-text school-logo-text--alt-color">
                          <a href="/landing"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a>
                        </h1>
                        <p><a class="site-footer__link" href="index.html">706-263-0175</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </footer>

</body>
    )
}


export default Register
```

I have tried adding more imports like from the `ScriptLoaded` file in the ../api/docs folder, however, it causes the whole page to go blank. If I get rid of the StandaloneSearchBox from `import {} from '@react-google-maps/api'` and from the `LoadScript GoogleMap` code, it has it on the page no problem, only it doesn't have the Search Bar and Markers to search for an address (`StandaloneSearchBox`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there was no library. In order for it to display the Search Box, there has to be a library. `const lib = ['places'];` is setting the places as a library and the library must be added to the `LoadScript` code where your API key goes. Updated code should have fixed the issue here:

```
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, StandaloneSearchBox } from '@react-google-maps/api'
const lib = ['places'];
const mapContainerStyle = {
  height: "400px",
  width: "800px"
}

const center = {
  lat: -3.745,
  lng: -38.523
};
  
const position = {
  lat: 37.772,
  lng: -122.214
}


const initialState = {
  company: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  isMember: true,
}

  const Register = () => {

    
    const [searchBox, setSearchBox] = useState(null);

  const handlePlacesChanged = () => console.log(searchBox.getPlaces());
  const handleLoad = ref => {
    setSearchBox(ref);
  };

    

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

  // global state and useNavigate
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
  }

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target)
  }

    
      return (
        <body class="page-template-default page page-id-13">
        <header class="site-header">
              <div class="container">
              <h1 class="school-logo-text float-left"><a href="/landing"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a></h1>
                         <div class="site-header__util">
                                        </div>
                </div>
                </header>

    <div class="page-banner">
     <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style={ { backgroundImage: "url('connection.jpg')" } }></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title">Register</h1>
        <div class="page-banner__intro">
            <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container container--narrow page-section">
  <h2 class="headline headline--tiny">Want to join and connect with companies? Sign up and get your company out there:</h2>
  
    <label class="header">Profile Photo:</label>
      <input id="image" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture></input>
    <label class="company-name">Company Name</label>
      <div class="company-input">
        <input text="headline headline--input" placeholder="Enter Company"></input>
      </div>
    <label class="company-email">Email</label>
          <div class="email-input">
          <input text="headline headline--input" placeholder="Enter Email"></input>
          </div>

     <label class="company-map">Map</label>   

    
  
    <LoadScript
    googleMapsApiKey='API_HERE'
    libraries={lib}
    >
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={10}
        >
          <>
           <StandaloneSearchBox
          onLoad={handleLoad}
          onPlacesChanged={handlePlacesChanged}
        >
          
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            style={{
              boxSizing: `border-box`,
              border: `1px solid transparent`,
              width: `240px`,
              height: `32px`,
              padding: `0 12px`,
              borderRadius: `3px`,
              boxShadow: `0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`,
              fontSize: `14px`,
              outline: `none`,
              textOverflow: `ellipses`,
              position: "absolute",
              left: "50%",
              marginLeft: "-120px"
            }}
          />
        </StandaloneSearchBox>
        </>
        </GoogleMap>
</LoadScript>
        </div>  
     

    <footer class="site-footer">
                  <div class="site-footer__inner container container--narrow">
                    <div class="group">
                      <div class="site-footer__col-one">
                        <h1 class="school-logo-text school-logo-text--alt-color">
                          <a href="/landing"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a>
                        </h1>
                        <p><a class="site-footer__link" href="index.html">706-263-0175</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </footer>

</body>
    )
}
  

export default Register
```